# Windows 10 - Updates are failing

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates

I have 2 updates that are failing to install in windows 10. Those 2 are, with the errors:

- Cumulative Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems (KB3081438) - Error 0x80070bc9
- Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems (KB3081704) - Error 0x80070643

I'm running win 10 64 bit upgraded from Windows 7. Anything I can do to install these without error?

I got KB3081438 installed, now it's just KB3081704.

Comment: 0x80070bc9 = ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED (The requested operation failed. A system reboot is required to roll back changes made.) I need to look at the setup logs. Copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS and the files "C:\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log", "C:\Windows\WinSxS\poqexec.log" to your desktop, put the folder and the files into 1 zip and upload the zip (OneDrive) and post a link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I was able to get KB3081438 installed, right now my only problem is KB3081704, with error 0x80070643

Comment: KB3081704 is the free DVD player app. Try the suggestions from here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/cant-install-update-kb3081704-error-0x80070643/99753f46-6dd1-4e3e-90ee-9ad732e7133c

Comment: From @Aegrion: try this if you still have issues:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-update-kb3081424-fails-to-install

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've done that, doesn't work. I'll try fixer1234's suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below steps to reset the Windows Updates Components:

```
Press Windows Key + X on the keyboard and then select “Command Prompt (Admin)” from the menu.
Stop the BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer and the Windows Update Services. To do this, type the following commands at a command prompt. Press the “ENTER” key after you type each command.

                       net stop wuauserv

                       net stop cryptSvc

                       net stop bits

                       net stop msiserver
```

3. Now rename the SoftwareDistribution and Catroot2 folder. You can do this by typing the following commands in the Command Prompt. Press the “ENTER” key after you type each command.

   ```
                     ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old

                     ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
   ```
4. Now, let’s restart the BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer and the Windows Update Services. Type the following commands in the Command Prompt for this. Press the ENTER key after you type each command.

   ```
                   net start wuauserv

                   net start cryptSvc

                   net start bits

                   net start msiserver
   ```
5. Type Exit in the Command Prompt to close it.

Answer (score -2):

Download the Windows 10 Media Creation tool here: http://aka.ms/windows10mediacreationtool

Do not under any circumstances format or wipe the drive of said computer beforehand or boot from USB or DVD as the upgrade needs to be conducted in-place.

More details can be found here:http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2015/08/13/step-by-step-how-to-clean-install-windows-10-without-formatting-the-drive.aspx

Comment: Uhm, is it really that important that I have to reinstall windows 10 completely?

Comment: My apologies as I misread the question. I thought you were still upgrading to Windows 10 from 7.  The following link will allow you to directly download the updates you require: http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/crup/2015/08/windows10.0-kb3081438-x64_a51f14406f23fcd8f2a323df6090fe9c98bf5981.msu